# Compressing class names and ids in HTML with Grunt

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, compression, classname

```
<div class="aAA J-KU-Jg J-KU-Jg-K9" ></div>
```

What is the name of this compression method being used by Gmail, and is there a grunt module for it?
This method scans each js, css, and html file, and shortens the class names and ids.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google uses Closure tools, e.g. [closure-stylesheets](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming).

Answer (score 0):

You can give grunt-class-id-minifier a go:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    class-id-minifier: {
        simple: {
            options: {
                jsMapFile: 'tmp/simple/map.js',
                jsMapDevFile: 'tmp/simple/map.dev.js',
                minifyFilter: function (k, type) {
                    // type.id type.className
                    // J_ ignored in minified html
                    return /^J_/.test(k) ? false : true;

                },
                jsMapFilter: function (k, type) {
                    // className ignored in js map
                    return !!type.id;
                }
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'test/fixtures/simple/',
                    src: '*.{html,css}',
                    dest: 'tmp/simple/'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-class-id-minifier